# UITextField has been clear text when app run background

Tags: ios, uitextfield, background-process

I've alternate problem with `UITextField`. Could you help me to solve it?

I have two `UITextField` when i input text into both `UITextField` and i put app to background mode then bring app to foreground. The text in `UITextField` still there. However, I want to CLEAR text from UITextField that i typed on `UITextField`.

You will save time of my life when you help solve it. Thanks.

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan -- if app goes to background the `viewDidDisappear` method is call

Comment: I did not implement code in method `viewDidDisappear`.

Comment: can you show your class code , it is easy to resolve

Comment: Changing the position of the UITextField in the view hierarchy in your Main view